# Error in Debugging Android Apps with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Today I try to create an Android apps use Xamarin. When I build the solution, I don't get any error report. But, unfortunately.., when I try to debug it, The Apps stop working and I get these error output:

```
05-15 14:15:42.812 D/Mono    (25078): Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x67fc68c8] -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0x67fd7378]: 1
05-15 14:15:42.812 D/Mono    (25078): Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0x67fc68c8] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
05-15 14:15:42.812 D/Mono    (25078): AOT module 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/system.mil.newsreader.system.mil.newsreader-2/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
05-15 14:15:42.812 D/Mono    (25078): AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/system.mil.newsreader.system.mil.newsreader-2/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
05-15 14:15:42.822 D/Mono    (25078): Unloading image data-0x67fe7008 [0x67fdf6d0].
05-15 14:15:42.822 D/Mono    (25078): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x647fd568] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0x67fc68c8]: 2
05-15 14:15:42.822 D/Mono    (25078): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x67fc68c8] -> mscorlib[0x5f265738]: 9
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078): Process: system.mil.newsreader.system.mil.newsreader, PID: 25078
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2277)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1802)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:703)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:764)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1642)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14970)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14970)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14970)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14970)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14970)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14970)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4635)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5625)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5124)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:613)
05-15 14:15:50.352 E/AndroidRuntime(25078):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

You can see, there's a line:

```
AOT module 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/system.mil.newsreader.system.mil.newsreader-2/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
```

Is there any solution for this problem..?

Comment: Did you try deleting the bin and obj folders and then build again.

Comment: Yes.., I already did that.., but unfortunately the problem still happen. I also try to re-install appcompat with nuget but still nothing..,

Comment: "AOT module 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed:"... Having the same issue here. 
There is a thread about it in xamarin forum (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/177930) but none of it seems to work here either